# Failed dependencies when installing heartbeat on RHEL 6.8

Tags: yum, rhel, rhel6, heartbeat

**Description of problem:
Failed dependencies when installing heartbeat on RHEL 6

Version-Release number of selected component (if applicable):

Cannot install heartbeat on RHEL 6.
Failed dependencies on libplumbgpl.so.2 and cluster-glue.
I have also tried to install using RHEL SUbscription repo & EPEL repo.

Error: Package: heartbeat-libs-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libplumbgpl.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: heartbeat-libs-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpils.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: heartbeat-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libplumb.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: heartbeat-libs-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libplumb.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: heartbeat-libs-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libstonith.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: heartbeat-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: cluster-glue
Error: Package: heartbeat-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: cluster-glue-libs

---

yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enabling
disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.
To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf

---

Error: Package: heartbeat-libs-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libplumbgpl.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: heartbeat-libs-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpils.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: heartbeat-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libplumb.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: heartbeat-libs-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libplumb.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: heartbeat-libs-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libstonith.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: heartbeat-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: cluster-glue
Error: Package: heartbeat-3.0.4-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: cluster-glue-libs
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
Expected results:
Heartbeat should be installed.

Additional info:
I have epel repo and RHEL subscription repo attached.Also I do have my system registered with RHEL.  System ID registered with RHEL: ID-1041056966

My question is how can i install heartbeat on RHEL 6.x 64 bit without Yum ?**

Comment: Steps to Reproduce:
    #mkdir 
    1.mkdir /root/heart/
    #downloading offline libraries , but doesnt work.it doesnt download all child libraries.
    2.yum --downloadonly install libplumbgpl  --downloaddir=/root/heart/

Comment: I've just had a quick look - both packages show up on yum, but have a long list of deps from the `base` and `updates` repos. Can you edit your question and use the 'code indent' options (to make it more readable) & your comment above should be included in the question. I can give you the output of my yum transaction if it helps - but I don't have a test box to install on and verify at the moment. Sorry